# How to Link MyAndroidApp to Google Assistant to redirect to a particular content present in my AndroidApp

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

As an example, I want to tell Google assistant
 
*"open xyz in myAndroidApp or show xyz in myAndroidApp"*

It should redirect to the app and open with the specific intent or data(deep linking)
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure this is currently possible right now. But a good first step would be looking into [app indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/)

Comment: app indexing from Google assistant?

Comment: Index your app to make it available from Google search on your phone.